# Curl from Jenkins workspace to docker container returning error

Tags: docker, jenkins, curl

I am trying to curl from Jenkins workspace to a Docker container. When I run my container I user -p 1080:1080 and after that I launch a curl from my workspace pointing to 127.0.0.1:1080. Doing that locally works fine but when I launch the code in Jenkins I get the following error :

I have changed the IP address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and now I can see that some data is received but still having connection reset error :

````
* About to connect() to 0.0.0.0 port 1080 (#0)

*   Trying 0.0.0.0...

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed


  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0) port 1080 (#0)

> PUT /mockserver/expectation HTTP/1.1

> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0

> Host: 0.0.0.0:1080

> Accept: */*

> Content-Length: 37894

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

> Expect: 100-continue

> 

* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer


  0 37894    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

* Closing connection 0

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

script returned exit code 56```
````

Comment: What is the curl command that you are trying ?

Comment: it's this one : ```for File in ${zip_path}/${expectation_rel_path}/*/*; do curl -v -X PUT "http://127.0.0.1:1080/mockserver/expectation" -d @${File}; done``` where in zip_path I have jsons files

Comment: Ok. Could you please update your question with the Jenkinsfile that you have tried.

Comment: jenkins file won't help we use an inhouse groovy library which specific functions. Here I have run my container this way : ```docker container run --name ${mock_server} -h mockserver -p 1080:1080 --net=${docker_shared_network} -d ${MOCKSERVER_IMAGE}:${MOCKSERVER_IMAGE_VERSION}```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by adding a sleep 20 into my shell script, this will wait until the service starts.